# How to type extended styled-component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript2.0, styled-components

**Typescript@2.8.1**, **styled-components@2.4.0**

I need to have one base styled-component that will be `.extend()`ed to create new ones, that are similar, to avoid code duplication.

I've come up with the following code that doesn't throw any error:

```
export interface Aprops {
  icon?: string;
}

export const A = styled<Aprops, 'div'>('div')`
  padding: ${(props) => (props.icon ? '10px' : '4px')};
`;

export interface Bprops {
  darkBackground?: boolean;
}

export const B = A.extend`
  background-color: ${(props: Bprops) =>
    props.darkBackground ? 'grey' : 'white'};
`;

function test() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <A icon="str1" />
      <B icon="str2" darkBackground />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

**Is there a way to rewrite line `export const B = A.extend` with `Bprops` properties specified on this level, like we have here: `export const A = styled<Aprops, 'div'>('div')`?**

Like `export const B = styled<Bprops & Aprops>(A)`, so I won't need to duplicate this code `(props: Bprops)` everywhere I need inside declaratino of component `B`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems I found solution:

```
export const B = styled<Aprops & Bprops>(A)`
  background-color: ${props =>
    props.darkBackground ? 'grey' : 'white'};
`;
```